# mark a single icon from many - vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am really confused.. I have a list of items with a heart-like "like" button. After the icon's clicked on I would like to change the color. But after this all my hearts change their colors, not only the one, which I pressed. Should I pass some argument in `markAsFavorite` method? Like index, or book?

```
 <template>
    <v-flex v-for="(book, index) in allBooks">
     <div>Title: {{ book.title }}</div>
     <i @click="markAsFavorite()" :class="{isActive: isMark}" class="fas fa-heart"></i>
 </template
 <script>
   name: 'Books',
   data () {
      return {
        allBooks: [
           { title: "one" },
           { title: "two" },
           { title: "three" },
           { title: "four" },
         ],
        isMark: false,
     }
   },
  methods: {       
    markAsFavorite() {
        this.isMark = !this.isMark
    },
   }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every object should have it property `isMark` as below:

**UPDATE:** you can merge properties to your original data after be fetched:

```js
const myData = [
  { title: "one"},
  { title: "two" },
  { title: "three" },
  { title: "four" },
]

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: true,
      allBooks: []
    }
  },
  
  created() {
    this.fetchAPI()
  },
  
  methods: {
    fetchAPI() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.allBooks = myData.map(item => ({...item, isMark: false }))
        this.isLoading = false
      }, 2000)
    },
    
    markAsFavorite(book) {
      book.isMark = !book.isMark
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.my-icon {  
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.isActive {
  color: red;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span v-if="isLoading">
    loading
    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  </span>
  
  <template v-else>
    <div class="flex" v-for="(book, index) in allBooks" :key="index">
      <div>Title: {{ book.title }}</div>
      <span
        :class="[
          { isActive: book.isMark }, 
          'my-icon'
        ]"
        @click="markAsFavorite(book)"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for this solution. It is really intresting. But what if allBooks array came from API? Then I can not add true or false.

Comment: wow! Thank you for that. Looks really intresting. I will try this methods :)

Answer (score 1):

I would separate out each *book* into its own component. That way it can track its own `isMark`

#### Book.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Title: {{ book.title }}</div>
    <i @click="markAsFavorite" :class="{isActive: isMark}" class="fas fa-heart"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Book',
  props: { book: Object },
  data: () => ({ isMark: false }),
  methods: {
    markAsFavorite () {
      this.isMark = !this.isMark
      this.$emit(this.isMark ? 'marked' : 'unmarked', this.book)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and then in your *Books* component

```html
<template>
  <v-flex v-for="(book, index) in allBooks" :key="index">
    <Book :book="book" @marked="handleMarked" @unmarked="handleUnmarked" />
  </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
import Book from './Book.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Books',
  components: { Book },
  // and so on
}
</script>
```

Comment: hmmm it's intresting. I will try and let you know, how it's working.